# IE11 Selenium getting error after logging selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11

Until login, it works fine. After login it is not working.

```
WebElement LoanNumber = driver.findElement(By.id("txtLoanNumber"));
LoanNumber.sendKeys("12345");
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #txtLoanNumber
```

For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Can you post the html of the page you are trying to use? The most likely case is that there is no element with an id of "txtLoanNumber", but it's a bit hard to judge without seeing the source.

Comment: You had mentioned that you are Login using your code and till then code is working fine. It can be possible that element you want to find is on the next page which displayed after login. But in your code, you are still referring the Login page and searching the element on it. In that situation above error can occur. If possible for you then you can provide a sample code for reproducing the issue. We will try to test it to find the cause for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.